# Is using exceptions for input validation bad for performance?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to run a function to check if the age entered by the user is enough for him to vote. I have done it with two ways

Both the codes are working well and both are working in the same way. I want to know if there are any performance differences in the two methods and which method should be used to perform such types of operations.

First Way :

```js
function validateAge() {

  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var paragraph = document.getElementById("result");

  if (age == "") {
    paragraph.innerHTML = "Please enter your age";
  } else if (age < 18) {
    paragraph.innerHTML = "You are too young to vote";
  } else {
    paragraph.innerHTML = "You are eligible to vote";
  }
}
```

```html
<title>Age validator</title>

<h1>Enter your age to check if you are eligible to vote : </h1>
<label>Enter Your age : </label>
<input type="text" id="age" /><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="validateAge()" value="Validate" /><br/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Second Way :

```js
function validateAge() {
  try {
    var agge = document.getElementById("age").value;

    if (agge == "") {
      throw "Please enter your age";
    } else if (agge < 18) {
      throw "You are too young to vote";
    } else {
      throw "You are eligible to vote";
    }
  } catch (obj) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = obj;
  }
}
```

```html
<title>Age validator</title>
<h1>Enter your age to check if you are eligible to vote : </h1>
<label>Enter Your age : </label>
<input type="text" id="age" /><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="validateAge()" value="Validate" /><br/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: I would use 2nd with some changes to it. Performance is too minimal to compare here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if there are any performance differences in the two methods...

Yes, marginally; typically using the exception mechanism is more costly than simply branching, though it's not a *big* difference in JavaScript (vs. some other languages) when what you throw isn't an `Error` (since when you don't create an `Error`, no stack information has to be captured).

> ...and which method should be used to perform such types of operations.

Typically, exception processing is for exceptional conditions, not expected ones. For what you describe, the standard approach would be the first one, simple branching. You might store the string in a simple variable and then assign to `innerHTML` after the `if`/`else if`/`else`:

```
function validateAge() {
  var agge = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var message;
  if (agge == "") {
    message = "Please enter your age";
  } else if (agge < 18) {
    message = "You are too young to vote";
  } else {
    message = "You are eligible to vote";
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = message;
}
```

```js
function validateAge() {
  var agge = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var message;
  if (agge == "") {
    message = "Please enter your age";
  } else if (agge < 18) {
    message = "You are too young to vote";
  } else {
    message = "You are eligible to vote";
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<title>Age validator</title>
<h1>Enter your age to check if you are eligible to vote : </h1>
<label>Enter Your age : </label>
<input type="text" id="age" /><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="validateAge()" value="Validate" /><br/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

...but that's mostly a matter of style.

---

Probably more significantly, though, it would be best to check that what the user has entered is actually a number. With your current code, if I write `seven` in the field, I'm told I'm eligible to vote, because `"seven" < 18` evaluates to `NaN < 18` which evalutes to `false`.

Comment: If I would change the type of input field from text to number, it will accept only numeric values. So,  this problem will not be faced.

Comment: @PraneetDixit - ...on browsers that implement it, yes. But intentionally and explicitly converting the string to number is best practice even then -- that or using `valueAsNumber` (which will be `undefined` on such browsers).

Comment: Interestingly enough it seems that `age < 18` casts the age to number before comparing it seems (in Chrome)

Comment: @mplungjan - Yes, `string < number` coerces the string to a number (so do `>`, `<=`, and `>=`). They all use the [abstract relational comparison](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison). `==` would compare them as numbers as well. The problem comes when you have a string that can't be converted to number, like `"seven"`, because that becomes `NaN` and `NaN < 18` is `false`, so the `else` branch is taken.

Answer (score 1):

You second code has to process a throw/catch

The following would likely be faster, but not noticeably so

```
var text;
if (age.trim() === "") text = "Please enter your age";
else if (isNaN(age)) text = "That is not an age";
else text = +age < 18 ? "You are too young to vote" : "You are eligible to vote";
paragraph.textContent = text;
```

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("validate").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var paragraph = document.getElementById("result");
    var text;

    if (age.trim() === "") text = "Please enter your age";
    else if (isNaN(age)) text = "That is not an age";
    else text = +age < 18 ? "You are too young to vote" : "You are eligible to vote";
    paragraph.textContent = text;
  });
});
```

```html
<title>Age validator</title>
<h1>Enter your age to check if you are eligible to vote : </h1>
<label>Enter Your age : </label>
<input type="text" id="age" /><br/>
<input type="button" id="validate" value="Validate" /><br/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be even faster.

```js
function validateAge() {
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = age?age<18?"You are too young to vote":"You are eligible to vote":"Please enter your age"
}
```

```html
<title>Age validator</title>

<h1>Enter your age to check if you are eligible to vote : </h1>
<label>Enter Your age : </label>
<input type="number" id="age" /><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="validateAge()" value="Validate" /><br/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: @mplungjan - Me too. But @ djcaesar9114: There's nothing whatsoever to suggest the above would be "even faster" than the OP's `if`/`else if`/`else`.